# Installation with sql server express edition

Tags: database, installation, deployment, mssql

I have developed a web portal in wordpress using xampp server. i have my database in my sql.

Now i need to deploy this wordpress portal on other system with sql server express edition.

So how can i deploy it successfully with sql server??

and what software or driver or service will be needed for this deployment on the system?

Answer (score 1):

We ported WP to SQL Server almost three years and have been maintaining it ever since.  Provided you are planning to use SQL Express 2012 or higher, this should be the solution you are looking for:

[Project Nami](http://projectnami.org)

Simply put, replacing `WPDB` isn't enough.  So we went a step further and rewrote any MySQL-specific syntax within Core.  Our primary reason for doing this was to take advantage of the native PaaS offerings from Azure.  Over the past three years it has grown to include others who want to run WordPress but for reasons of policy, principle, or simple preference do not run MySQL.  They range from SQL Server user groups to Fortune 100 companies looking to maximize investment in their current DBAs.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a **requirement** for running wordpress. Asking if you can run it on another SQL DB is like asking if you can run it on the new hack language which is similar to PHP. It might work or not, but basically you are totally on your own, and for sure it is not something that you do as an afterthought after the project is almost done, this is something you should start the development with.

if you still wish to investigate the possibility, you should start with replacing the DB access driver, the `WPDB` class, with a class that implements the same interface but uses the mssql related php api instead of the mysql one. Even after that you will have to test well as much functionality as possible as the SQL supported by the various DB is almost, but not exactly, the same.